# Contact Form PHP and HTML error

Tags: php, html, contact-form

I have created a contact form using HTML and PHP but I have two problems with the code:
**First:** when I press submit there is no message sent to my mail and I receive this error[Line 25 error is : mail($to, $subject, $header, $body_message);][1].

**Second:** I got an error when I open contact.php file as shown in the picture[those errors related to attached file][2]

Finally, I would ask please if anyone can send me a reference on how I can send the attached file to email as I didn't find any helping adds for that

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<h2>Contact Form</h2>
<p><span style="color: red" >*Required field</span></p>
<form action="contact.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 First Name:<input type="text" name="fname"><span style="color: red" >*</span><br><br>
 Last Name:<input type="text" name="lname"><span style="color: red" >*</span><br><br>
 E-mail:<input type="text" name="email"><span style="color: red" >*</span><br><br>
 Telephone:<input type="text" name="tel"><br><br>
 Designation:<select name="design">
    <option value="Architectural Engineer">Architectural Engineer</option>
    <option value="Structural Engineer">Structural Engineer</option>
    <option value="Draughts-man">Draughts-man</option>
    <option value="Receptionist">Receptionist</option>
    <option value="Secertary">Secertary</option>
   </select><br><br>
   Country Applied From:<select name="country">
  <option value="">Country...</option>
  <option value="Afganistan">Afghanistan</option>
  <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
  <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
  <option value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option>
</select><br><br>
 Message:<textarea name="message"></textarea> <br><br>
 Upload Your Resume:<span style="color: red" >*</span><input type="file" name="uploaded_file"><br><br> 
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
 <input type="reset" value="clear">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP Code:

```html
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$fname = $_POST['fname']; 
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$email = $_POST['email']; 
$tel = $_POST['tel'];
$design = $_POST['design'];
$country = $_POST['country'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$to = 'eng.bolaraafat@hotmail.com';
$subject = 'Contact Form'.$fname;
$header = "$email";
$body_message = 'From: '.$fname .$lname."\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Telephone: '.$tel."\n";
$body_message .= 'Designation: '.$design."\n";
$body_message .= 'Country Appled From: '.$country."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '.$message."\n";
 mail($to, $subject, $header, $body_message);
}

$name_of_uploaded_file = basename($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
$type_of_uploaded_file = substr($name_of_uploaded_file, strrpos($name_of_uploaded_file, '.') + 1);
$size_of_uploaded_file = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["size"]/1048576;//size in MBs
$max_allowed_file_size = 500; // size in KB
$allowed_extensions = array("jpg", "pdf", "docx", "doc");

if($size_of_uploaded_file > $max_allowed_file_size ) {
    $errors .= "\n Size of file should be less than $max_allowed_file_size";
}
//------ Validate the file extension -----
$allowed_ext = false;
for($i=0; $i<sizeof($allowed_extensions); $i++)
{
    if(strcasecmp($allowed_extensions[$i],$type_of_uploaded_file) == 0) {
         $allowed_ext = true;
    }
}
if(!$allowed_ext) {
     $errors .= "\n The uploaded file is not supported file type. ".
" Only the following file types are supported: ".implode(',',$allowed_extensions);
}
?>
```

Comment: **Too much code**. You need to do a better job of troubleshooting this yourself. We are *not* debuggers. You need **isolate the problem** and debug from there. If you're stuck provide a **clear explanation of what isn't working** with a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

Your email code should be as below:-

```
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();  

$isSuccess =  mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

if( $isSuccess == true ) { // if mail is successfully sent 
   echo "Message sent successfully...";
}else{
   echo "Message could not be sent...";
}
```

Read [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it looks like its not working is that you have the message and headers order mixed up in the PHP mail function.

You have written:

```
mail($to, $subject, $header, $body_message);
```

Correct Format:
mail($to, $subject, $body_message, $header);

**PHP Mail()**

```
bool mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php